# Selenium remote driver issue with HtmlUnit driver

Tags: selenium, htmlunit-driver

[i'm seeing the issue with Selenium remote driver when I'm executing the script with Htmlunit driver.
Note 1:- Same script works without any issue when I'm running with Firefox driver.]
Note 2: My browser had security authentication process for whatever the site i open, Not sure if that have ant role in this.

I have observed the selenium remote driver under maven shows with little different icon in left pane.
I feel its jar file loading issue.
I tried to put the selenium remote driver manually into .m2 repository.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6XJX.png)

Error message:-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/SessionNotFoundException
    at TestPackage.titleNUrlCheckingTest.main(titleNUrlCheckingTest.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 1 more
```

[enter image description here][2]

Comment: Please use latest 2.26 version, otherwise post your complete pom.xml

Comment: i'm using selenium -remote-driver version 3.3.1

Comment: <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Which htmlunit-driver version? Other dependencies are transitive

Answer (score 3):

You need to use latest version, note the change of `artifactId` from old versions.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.26</version>
</dependency>
```

which depends on

`selenium-api` 3.3.1

**Update:**

Your pom.xml works with simple test case of HtmlUnitDriver, but there is a potential conflict of versions, you should exclude HtmlUnitDriver 2.24 from selenium-java 3.3.1:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Also, try to remove all selenium dependencies, and have only `htmlunit-driver`, all needed dependencies are automatically handled by maven.

Comment: Seems like `htmlunit` folder missing from latest version jar [htmlunit-driver-2.26-with-dependencies.jar] https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/htmlunit-driver/releases
Can you please take a look?

Comment: I have added the above dependency for htmlunit-driver with 2.26, refreshed & rerun..still seeing the issue.

Comment: @Rajesh-Varma Then please post your complete pom.

Comment: @SameerPatil: the file has `com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit` folder, please open a new ticket describing your issue in detail.

Comment: @Ahmed Ashour , File length is not fitting in the given space,  plz provide the email id so that I can send the file

Comment: mail sent , plz check and let meknow

Comment: My observation is only regarding `HtmlUnitDriver` class which is not present in jar having version '2.26' whereas it is present in '2.25'

Comment: @Ahmed: Thanks !

Comment: i got it working , not sure what changes effected, i have created a new project from scratch

Answer (score 2):

Please update your POM XML file with latest version of htmlunit dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
  <version>2.32.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and remove if you have something like

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.52.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and update project. This should resolve your exception issue.

Reference: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4930

Comment: For those overlook, notice the differenence in `<artifactId>`.  It is `not` selenium-htmlunit-driver.